# Semantic UI - grid with variable number of columns on mobile, tablet and computer

Tags: python, django, django-templates, semantic-ui

I have user images which adjust their sizes depending on the number of columns in the grid.

Right now I have:

```
<div class="ui ten column grid">
  {% for user in event.participants.all %}
  <div class="center aligned column">
    <a href="{% url 'profiles:profile' user.username %}"><img class="ui circular small centered image" src="{{ user.profile.get_avatar_url }}"></a>
    <p>{{ user.username }}</p>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And everything works fine except that on small devices profile images decrease in size dramatically, because of "ten column grid" which is applied for mobile devices as well as for computers.

I know that for columns inside grid it is possible to declare:

```
<div class="sixteen wide mobile twelve wide tablet ten wide computer column">
```

but it won't work if I use it for grid itself:

```
<div class="ui sixteen wide mobile twelve wide tablet ten wide computer column grid">
```

How can I create grid which will have different number of columns on mobile, tablet and computer?

Answer (score 2):

The column size must be declared on each `.column`. Not on the grid.

Also you need the `.stackable` class in order to wrap your columns.

See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vfpv0jzd/2/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately this solution is not working for me, because if to make grid stackable the profile image will take one row, another image will be on the next row and so on. I want seven pictures to be displayed in one row on mobile devices